# Sync version of async method in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, asynchronous, synchronous

What's the best way to make a synchronous version of an asynchronous method in Objective-C (for iOS, in case it matters)?

Say you have a class with these two methods:

```
- (void) asyncDoSomething; // Starts an asynchronous task. Can't be changed.
- (void) onFinishDoSomething; // Called when the task is finished
```

How would you implement a synchronous `doSomething` that does not return until the task is finished?

Comment: I assume you cannot modify your 2 methods ? If this is launch in the UI thread that will be a bad idea to block and wait for the result. What is this for exactly ?

Comment: No, it won't be launched in the UI thread. It's for a HTML to bitmap generator that uses platform and legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you can declare a global boolean that will tell you to continue or wait, just before calling your `- (void)asyncDoSomething;` method you set your `BOOL wait` to `YES` and after the method you do

```
while (wait) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
}
```

to wait for your response, and in you async callback `- (void)onFinishDoSomething;` you set your boolean to `NO`;

This way, your method is still called asynchronous but the code after is not executed before the response. It will wait like if it was synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the asyncDoSomething implementation and remove the NSThread/NSOperation/callback code.

Comment: Can't change that method. Will clarify.